# Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, conda

I'm running the following command in continuous integration (not locally on a machine):

```
conda env create -f python/env/foo.yml && conda init bash && conda activate foo
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Since it's CI and I can't open a new shell in CI, how do I have the same effect so that I can use conda activate?

Comment: `conda` has to be configured for your CI tool to be used. You can investigate to see how your ENV looks like and setup `conda` to be as such. Probably you're using Ubuntu or some other distro. Each distro has its own conventions, your process is forked from the process of the CI tool ... so you can reverse engineer and make it work, but would require more info in the channel to be able to help.

Comment: I'm using the github ci. How to configure conda for that. And also using Ubuntu. Also tried doing source ~/.bashrc after conda init bash, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conda init` command is for adding code to the shell resource file, providing functionality (like `conda activate`) for interactive shell sessions. Since CI sessions usually transient, one instead should just source the `etc/profile.d/conda.sh` directly to add `conda activate` support.

Something like:

```bash
conda env create -f python/env/foo.yml \
  && . "$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" \
  && conda activate foo
```